# What is the difference between regex operations in math and regex in UNIX / Linux?

Tags: computer-science, computability, automata, regular-expressions

What is the difference between regular expression operations (union, concatenation, kleene star) and regular expression (implemented in UNIX and can be used together with the grep command)?

Are there such methods that are implemented in UNIX and can be used together with the grep command, that cannot be recreated using only the regular expression operations (union, concatenation, kleene star)

regular expression (implemented in UNIX and can be used together with the grep command) :

```
(.,*,^,$,\,\<,|>,[],+,?,&,\n))
```

Answer (score 2):

Regular Expressions in formal languages and automaton theory are the basis for regular expressions in UNIX. Some of the syntax is a bit different in grep than in the formal theory. For example, in grep, you can use $(a+b)^{2}$, while this is not acceptable syntax theoretically (though it would make sense to have it theoretically). Grep also has a larger set of symbols it allows in regular expression syntax.

Grep (at least some versions of it) use finite state automaton to handle the search.

I am not a *Nix expert, nor am I a formal languages expert. Someone may have more enlightening answers than I did. Hopefully this helps some, though.

Comment: Theoretically, it is acceptable. BTW, if understand what you mean by {a,b}^2, this is perfectly expressible with the mathematical regular syntax and is indeed regular. What's not regular is {a}^n because no matter how big you build your FA, you can have a string that is longer. See [pumping lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages).

Comment: I'm not talking about context free grammars. With a regular expression $(a + b)(a + b)$ is the correct syntax (I'm pretty sure at least, but it's late and I may have made a mistake), but grep allows for something more along the lines of $(a + b)^{2}$. It's been a couple years since I've worked with grep, but I think that's the syntax.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `(a+b)(a+b)`. What strings match? What do you mean by the parenthesis and the plus sign? Are they simply symbols to match against? Using the power superscript is not strictly in the base definition of regular expressions, but is simply syntactic sugar that doesn't increase the power of regular expressions. The bigger difference between mathematical regular expressions and regexes in grep, etc is the fact that regexes aren't regular any more because of unbounded backreferences.

Comment: @starflyer (a+b)(a+b) is what would be written in grep syntax as (a|b)(a|b).  It matches the strings aa, ab, ba, bb.

Comment: @Ted, ok thanks. So just to repeat, that is indeed syntactical difference which does not add any power. On the other hand, back references make the language non regular.

Answer (score 2):

The mathematical (theoretical CS) definition of regular is that which is recognized by a [NFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton) or [DFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton). Equivalently it can be generated by a [regular grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar).

Regexes are things that have popular implementations in Perl, Python, grep, etc. I won't call them regular expressions because for most (all?) of the modern implementations, they are not regular anymore.

The reason that regexes aren't regular anymore is the back reference feature. This makes it at least as powerful as a [context-free grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_free_grammar). Unlimited backreferences make it even more powerful than CFGs.

As an example written in Python:

```
import re
myre = re.compile( "(.*)-\\1" )
m = myre.match( "abcdefg-abcdefg" )
if m:
    print m.group(1)
```

The mathematical definition of regular simply does not allow this kind of power.

Comment: The class of languages described by regular expressions with backreferences is neither a superset nor a subset of the context-free languages. For example, $\{ww^R\mid w\in\Sigma^\ast\}$ is the canonical example of a context-free language, but is not representable by a regex with backreferences; $\{w^2\mid w\in\Sigma^\ast\}$ is not context-free but is represented by the regex `/^(.*)\1$/`.

Answer (score -1):

Regular Expressions is a formal language defined by induction with a finite set of rules. You have some info over here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularExpression.html